# error compiling android cordova when change versionCode with plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I have a problem when i try to compile Android version of my app after change versionCode in AndroidManifest.xml. I also discovered that compilation failed only when plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer is installed. With the plugin installed after i change versionCode in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml (i change value from 1 to 2) i obtain this error compiling.

```
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava
/Users/myuser/Desktop/hometube/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/LocalFilesystem.java:414: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/myuser/Desktop/hometube/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/LocalFilesystem.java:416: error: cannot find symbol
            for (File f : context.getExternalMediaDirs()) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getExternalMediaDirs()
  location: variable context of type Context
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks to all

Comment: The problem is with the `cordova-plugin-file` installed with the `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`. Can you mention the API level of the app you are building? and also can you add the line what you actually changed?